# css overlay: how do I maintain "relative" position on a "fixed" element?

Tags: css

I have a simple css/js animation that I have styled with 'position: fixed' attribute so that it overlays other elements on the page.

However, I still want the animation to position itself relative to other elements and while this appears to work OK on a full-width page, it goes awry on mobile layouts.

Here's a quick example: https://codepen.io/Megistus/pen/poLGbyL

```
body{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.body-sw {
  background-color: none;
  height: 20vh; 
  display: block;
  //align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 3%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sound-wave {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  //justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.body-sw .bar {
  animation-name: wave-lg;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background: #006565;
  margin: 0 1.5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 1px;
}
.body-sw .bar:nth-child(-n+7), .body-sw .bar:nth-last-child(-n+7) {
  animation-name: wave-md;
}
.body-sw .bar:nth-child(-n+3), .body-sw .bar:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  animation-name: wave-sm;
}

@keyframes wave-sm {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@keyframes wave-md {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes wave-lg {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

(excuse the messy css, there's a lot of unnecessary guff in there!)

As you can see, I'm hoping got the animation to maintain its position between the "LOGO" div above and the "content" div below, but for the expanded "bars" in the animation to overlay the elements above and below it when the animation plays (on page load).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not want to use `position: fixed;`. This will forced the element to a fixed position on the page.

Instead, you can set `position: absolute;`, which will give you what seems to be the same result, however if you modify your HTML a little, you can get the animation to stay with the logo.

You need to place the animation elements inside of a *container* that holds both the logo and the animation. Then if you set this parent *container* to `position: relative;` now your animation elements will stay with the logo and the `position: absolute;` you set will allow the animation to overlay the logo still.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const bar = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
  for (let i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
    bar.forEach((item, j) => {
      // Random move
      item.style.animationDuration = `${Math.random() * (0.7 - 0.2) + 0.2}s`; // Change the numbers for speed / ( max - min ) + min / ex. ( 0.5 - 0.1 ) + 0.1
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.logo { position: relative; }
.body-sw {
  background-color: none;
  height: 20vh; 
  display: block;
  //align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.5em;
  left: -.5em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sound-wave {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  //justify-content: center;
}
.body-sw .bar {
  animation-name: wave-lg;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background: #006565;
  margin: 0 1.5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 1px;
}
.body-sw .bar:nth-child(-n+7), .body-sw .bar:nth-last-child(-n+7) {
  animation-name: wave-md;
}
.body-sw .bar:nth-child(-n+3), .body-sw .bar:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  animation-name: wave-sm;
}

@keyframes wave-sm {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@keyframes wave-md {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes wave-lg {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.35;
    height: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
    <div class="body-sw">
      <div class='sound-wave'>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div>   
    <h1>Content....</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have put me on the right track.

Comment: What seems to work is to change all the divs to relative, NOT to have the divs nested, but rather play around with a negative value for the top/bottom margins... I've updated the codepen with borders to show what's going on. https://codepen.io/Megistus/pen/poLGbyL --- seems to work pretty well across different browser widths

Comment: ...the only thing I can't quite figure out is why there is a margin above and below the content of the "logo" div and the "content" div... have tried margin: 0px and padding: 0px but doesn't make any difference

Comment: @dsb27 The extra space you are seeing around your `logo` and `content` div areas is not because of the div itself, but because of the `<h1>` tag inside. By default **H1** tags have a margin. So try `.logo div { margin: 0; }` in your CSS